Why does the return type change depending on if I use a ternary operator or not?
I have two IMHO identical piece of code (even Rider suggest me to shorten the 2nd with the 1st option), but giving different results (.NET 8)
public static object Foo1()
{
    int valTrue = 5;
    decimal valFalse = 10m;
    return true ? valTrue : valFalse;
}

public static object Foo2()
{
    int valTrue = 5;
    decimal valFalse = 10m;
    
    if (true)
        return valTrue; 
    else
        return valFalse;
}

If I run them like this:
Console.WriteLine(Foo1().GetType().Name);
Console.WriteLine(Foo2().GetType().Name);

The output of Foo1, which uses the ternary operator, returns Decimal, while the output of Foo2, which uses an if statement, returns Int32. Why is that?

Are you saying that i in the first code block gets casts to a Decimal because of the ternary operator? https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQMwAJboMLoN7LpGYYD2ARgFYCmAxgC4D86AsgBQCU+hxvUcAOgAq1AB70BAKQDOpAHZTZcgKIAbagFtqc+ugBO1AIbBqe9AF50c6gHdOAbh68iUAOz6jJvcL0BPAOLU9ACSOqgwbKQArroAljrosVzMseggHsamAoH0ACJ0sRqGqg5O6AC+yOVAA==

It does seem like there's a slight difference in type-inference, type-casting between the two examples.  Microsoft does say that: "If a target type of a conditional expression is unknown (for example, when you use the var keyword) the type of consequent and alternative must be the same or there must be an implicit conversion from one type to the other."

@gunr2171 thanks a lot, now when I know the answer the repro sample can be simplified easily.

Short answer is ternary does a conversion before evaluating.  Joel Coehoorn explains why the int is converted and not the decimal in this example.  Your if/else does no conversion at all.

Yeah, you're ending up with (object)(true ? (decimal)valTrue : valFalse). Though the behaviour of ternary expressions has changed, to allow picking a type based on how the value is used. That doesn't apply in this case, since int has an implicit conversion to decimal.

For the first option, if the types of the two results of the ternary expression don't match exactly, there must be an implicit conversion from one to the other, and first the eligible option is selected.
For an int -> decimal conversion, this is a widening conversion (no information is lost because a decimal can express every possible int value), and so an implicit conversion is provided. But the decimal -> int conversion is narrowing (some information is lost, and there's even the potential for an overflow), so an explicit conversion must be used. Therefore the result of the ternary expression is typed as a decimal, regardless of what was true/false for the conditional expression.
For the second option, we have multiple separate expressions, so the compiler is free to use a distinct type for the separate lines.
Both cases feature the return keyword, where the ultimate result is determined by the type used with the method declaration... but again, in the event of a narrowing conversion an explicit cast should be used.

Confirmed! Modifying statement to return reader.TryGetInt32(out int i) ? (object)i : reader.GetDecimal(); solved my troubles.

Just the invalid Rider's optimization confuses me even more...
